# No animation options showing in CompizConfig Settings Manager

Tags: compiz, customization, animations

This is what my "Animations" option looks like in CCSM:

[image]

It was working fine before. Then I installed Macbuntu, didn't like it and then uninstalled it. After that it hasn't worked.

How to get the animations back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, macubuntu is no longer developed, so, don't ever install it!
You should try to completely remove compiz and install it once again. It looks like that macubuntu broken some dependicies. If it will not help, only system reinstallation can help you.

Answer (score 2):

**1.---------------->**

```
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

**2.---------------->**

Reset System

**3.---------------->**

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

**4.---------------->**

Reset System

Comment: "Reset System" to be understood as restarting the computer...

Comment: @ebrasha What's the benefit of running as separate `install` command for each package? Is there any reason not to use `sudo apt-get install unity-2d ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-2d compizconfig-settings-manager xserver-xgl emerald compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-extra unity`? Also, why include `git`?

Comment: Looks way more badass to do it individually imo!